# How to match up dates on 2 different tables and join to an ID table?

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata

I have a table full of product ids and their attributes. I want to join sales data and receipt data from 2 different tables and a different row for each id and date combo. So I want the output to look like this:

[image: example]

I tried joining the product id table and sales table to the receipt table but I'm not sure how to get the dates from the sales and receipts table to match up. Not sure of how to approach this. Thanks!

Comment: Please give the code you tried. When writing a join you can specify a filter as well to match the dates.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! SQL questions are best served with sample data and expected output. Data structures is the language that we all share.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `mysql` or `teradata`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the counts for each table and combine them usung UNION ALL

```
select
   product_id
  ,sales_date
   -- combine the counts from both tables
  ,sum(sales_count)
  ,sum(receipt_count)
from
 (
   -- get the counts for the sales table
   select
      product_id
     ,sales_date
     ,count(*) as sales_count
      -- UNION needs the same number of columns in both Select -> adding a dummy column
      -- 1st Select determines the datatype
     ,cast(0 as int) as receipt_count
   from sales 
   group by product_id, sales_date

   UNION ALL

   -- get the counts for the receipts table
   select
      product_id
     ,receipt_date
     ,0
     ,count(*) 
   from receipts 
   group by product_id, receipt_date
 ) as dt
group by product_id, receipt_date
```

Comment: thanks this worked! I just have too much data now haha

Answer (score -1):

```
select p.product_id, s.sales_date, s.sales_count, r.receipt_count
from
  products p,
  (select count(*) sales_count, sales_date, product_id from sales group by 2,3) s
  (select count(*) receipt_count, receipt_date, product_id from receipts group by 2,3) r
where 
  p.product_id = s.product_id
  and p.product_id = r.product_id
  and s.sales_date=r.receipt_date
;
```